# Элементы в ряд HTML

Tags: html, css

пишу интернет магазин с нуля (вообще ничего не знаю про php и css)

И мне нужно как-то сделать что бы элементы шли в ряд, (1 картинка - это как сейчас, 2 картинка - это приемлемый результат)

```
<div>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
            <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
            <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

вот css

```
.shop{
    margin-top: 15px;
    max-width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 200px;
    border-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.text-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shop h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Подскажите как это сделать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первым надо убрать с контейнера с классом `shop` `max-width`, что бы ваши элементы могли по ряду поместиться, или сделать высоту побольше, и контейнер с классом `text-wrapper` то же надо задать `float` и фиксировать высоту.

```css
.shop{
    margin-top: 15px;
    /*max-width: 200px;*/
    max-height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 200px;
    border-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper{
  float: left;
}
.img-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.text-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    max-width: 100px;
}
.shop h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
            <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
            <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

И еще я поместил картинку и текст той картинки в обертку, что бы при разных разрешениях текст не скидывался в низ бес своей картинки (при маленьких разрешениях).

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, прочитайте про html, css, javascript и php(или другое). Очень пригодиться для интернет магазина. А чтобы сделать в ряд

```
.img-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text-wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

или

```
.img-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text-wrapper {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Есть и другие способы типа flex.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал использовать inline-block т.к. к элементу с float будут прикладыватся другие элементы без float

```css
.shop{
    margin-top: 15px;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-top: 200px;
    border-width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
.text-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.shop h4 {
    margin: 0;
}
.group {
display:inline-block;
max-width:200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="shop">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
            <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img        src="http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/farcry/images/7/73/FC4_KEYART_PACK-610x722.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140515173131">
        </div>
        <div class="text-wrapper">
            <h4>Far Cry 4</h4>
            <p>Купить аккаунт с игрой за 10 рублей!</p>
        </div>
         </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```